# GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker - Access to the path 'C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile' is denied

Tags: c#, google-analytics, google-reporting-api

I'm using the Google Analytics reporting API v4 (c#) to get data. I use this code below to authorize. On my local machine evering works fine. But on my production-server I get the error: "Access to the path 'C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile' is denied."
It's not related to folder/file read write permissions because I read from an online sorce. I can't figure this one out.... Heres my code:

var client = new WebClient();

```
var stream = client.OpenRead("https://api.myjson.com/bins/drj87");

var loginEmailAddress = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AnalyticsReporting.Email"];

return await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
    new[] { AnalyticsReportingService.Scope.Analytics },
    loginEmailAddress, CancellationToken.None,
    new FileDataStore("GoogleAnalyticsApiConsole"));
```

Answer (score 0):

From https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/reference/1.9.1/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1Util_1_1Store_1_1FileDataStore:

```
Google.Apis.Util.Store.FileDataStore.FileDataStore(string folder, bool fullPath = false)
```

> Constructs a new file data store. If fullPath is
>   false the path will be used as relative to
>   Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData, otherwise the input folder
>   will be treated as absolute. The folder is created if it doesn't exist
>   yet.

So put the full path of a directory your service account *does* have permissions to, and set fullPath to true.

Comment: But how do I pick a folder inside my project? Let's say classic App_Data-folder.. In production I only have access to folders created inside my project

Comment: Put it in the config file? Or use the FullPath of the current executable to find the path to your application?